# Notepad++ Regex Find and Replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have sample data file with following format data

```
Data_Set = "001" , Status = "TRUE" ;
Data_Set = "002" , Status = "TRUE" ;
Data_Set = "003" , Status = "TRUE" ;
Data_Set = "004" , Status = "TRUE" ;
Data_Set = "005" , Status = "TRUE" ;
Data_Set = "006" , Status = "TRUE" ;
```

and I want replace all above data as below format

```
RMV_Set = "001" , Status = "TRUE" ; (mistake)
```

Corrected , required output

```
RMV_Set = "001" , Status = "001" ;
RMV_Set = "002" , Status = "002" ;
RMV_Set = "003" , Status = "003" ;
RMV_Set = "004" , Status = "004" ;
RMV_Set  = "005" , Status = "005" ;
RMV_Set = "006" , Status = "006" ;
```

I have tried following Regex method in Notepad++ and it won't work, please help me solve this

```
**Find** : Data_Set = "[0-9]*" , Status = "TRUE" ;
**Replace** : RMV_Set = "$1" , Status = "TRUE" ;
```

Comment: **Find** `Data_` **Replace** `RMV_`

Comment: `"[0-9]*"` => `"([0-9]*)"`, you are missing the capturing group. If context is important, if `Data_Set` should only be changed when followed with `, Status = "TRUE"`, then a regex **is** necessary.

Comment: As Zenoo said, you don't need a regex for this.

Comment: @Carra He needs if he doesn't want to manipulate a `Data_Set` that its status is `FALSE` or occurs somewhere else in context.

Comment: Hi All , actually i made a mistake , my requirement something different from above RMV_Set = "001" , Status = "001" ; kind of replacement i want

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `Data_Set` with `RMV_Set` why you need regex for this?

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to replace every occurrence of `Data_` in your file

You can avoid using a RegEx and just :

**Find** `Data_`

**Replace** `RMV_`

> If you need to make sure to only replace in the right context

You can use this RegEx : [`Data_Set ?= ?("\d+")(?= ?, ?Status ?= ?"TRUE" ?;)`](https://regex101.com/r/AeHC5v/1)

- `Data_Set ?= ?` matches `Data_Set =` literally with or without spaces
- `("\d+")` captures one or more digits surrounded by `""`
- `(?= ?, ?Status ?= ?"TRUE" ?;)` `(?= ... )` makes sure the following expression is found after your match.

**Find** `Data_Set ?= ?("\d+")(?= ?, ?Status ?= ?"TRUE" ?;)`

**Replace** `RMV_Set = $1`

**[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/AeHC5v/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Also try my solution as well

Find what: `data(_.*")(\d+")(.*")true"` 
Replace with: `RMV$1$2$3$2`